# Finding program that enumerates a language using Von Neumman's computability paradigm

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, logic, enumeration

Given an alphabet $\Sigma$ of $n$ elements, whenever there is some order $\leq$ over the elements of $\Sigma$, we define $s^{\leq} : \Sigma^{*} \mapsto \Sigma^{*}$ as

\begin{align*}
    s^{\leq} \left( (a_n)^m \right)  &= (a_1)^{m + 1} & m \geq 0\\ 
    s^{\leq} \left( \alpha a_i (a_n)^{m} \right) &= \alpha a_{i+1} (a_1)^{m} & 1
    \leq i < n, m \geq 0
\end{align*}

Assume $\Sigma = \{@, !\}$ with $@ < ~!$. The function $s^{\leq}$ enumerates the language as follows:

\begin{align*}
    \epsilon, @, !, @ @, @ !, !@, !!, @@@, @@!, @!@, @!!, !@@, !@!, !!@, !!!, \ldots
\end{align*}

I was asked to formulate a formal program that, given an input $\alpha \in \Sigma^{*}$, outputs $s^{\leq}(\alpha)$. The program has infinitely many numeric variables, which we denote $N_1, N_2, \ldots$ and infinitely many alphabetic variables (strings) which we denote $P_1, P_2, \ldots$. To say that the program "outputs" an alphabetic value (e.g. $s^{\leq}(\alpha)$ is to say that this value is stored in $P_1$, the first alphabetic variable, when the program halts. When the program starts, $P_1$ is automatically set to the input $\alpha$ and all other alphabetic variables are set to $\epsilon$, the empty string. All numeric variables begin with the value of $0$.

The valid operations are:

- Add or substract $1$ to any numeric variable.
- Append a character of $\Sigma$ to any alphabetic variable.
- Check if a numeric variable is zero and, if so, jump to any instruction.
- Check if an alphabetic variable begins with $a \in \Sigma^{*}$ and, if so, jump to any instruction.
- Jump to any instruction.
- Copy the content of a variable onto another variable.
- Remove the first character from an alphabetic variable.

Using these and only these instructions, how can one produce a program that outputs $s^{\leq}$? The challenge I find is that the given instructions permit us to direct the course of the program depending on the initial character of an alphabetic character. However, when $P_1$ is set to $\alpha$ at the beginning of the program, the most important question seems to be what is the *last* character of $\alpha$.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/165391/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4856825/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).